# Mapping unsigned char * in JNA

Tags: java, jna

I have a C function which has a signature

```c
void test (unsigned char * p)
```

The JNA code for this function is generated as

```java
void test(Pointer p);

void test(ByteBuffer b);
```

I have tried with the Pointer mapping, where `DataLen` is the actual length of data which is being pulled from a file header.

```java
Pointer p =new Memory(DataLen*2); 
p.setString(0, str); 
p.setMemory(0 + str.length(), 1, (byte)(0));
System.out.println("HAHAHA" + p.getString(0));
```

This last statement should give me all the data from the pointer but it gives me just few bytes.

If I don't multiply by 2 I get an error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=14070, offset=25097

How can I call this function in Java using JNA Pointer?

Comment: I'm using this code and when I print what's in Pointer, I don't get all bytes

Pointer p  =new Memory(DataLen*2);
            p.setString(0,str);
            System.out.println(p.getString(0));

Comment: "this code" is which code?  Where did you get DataLen?  What is missing? Did you add a byte (or 2 bytes for UTF16) for null terminator?  You really need to provide more code and more details, otherwise we are just guessing at your problem.

Comment: Here is what I have
// DataLen is the actual lenght of data which is being pulled from Header of a file. This file is custom file  if I don't multiply by 2 I Get an error saying
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space : size=14070, offset=25097

 


Pointer p  =new Memory(DataLen*2); 
            p.setString(0,str);
            p.setMemory(0 + str.length(), 1, (byte)(0));
            System.out.println("HAHAHA" + p.getString(0));


this last statement should give me all the data from the pointer but it gives me just few bytes.

Comment: This seems like you have a string of length 25097.  Where does the string come from?  Where do you call the `test()` function?   What is the encoding of your String?

Comment: Thanks for your help. The String is being read from a file. This data is coming from a satellite feed. I think that is being written in C. We don't own that piece of code.  After digging around found and used US_ASCII encoding that fixed the length issue but when I try to read the string back from the pointer, I don't get the entire string back, I only get first 16 bytes only.


 Pointer p  =new Memory( str.length() +1);
            p.setString(0,str,"US-ASCII");
            p.setMemory(0 + str.length(), 1, (byte)(0));
            System.out.println("HAHAHA" + p.getString(0,"US-ASCII"));

Comment: The `Pointer` class `getString()` stops at the first null byte when reading ASCII.  So if your received data has any null bytes in it, that's where it stops.  If there's more data, you'll need to iterate over it and read past the nulls.

Comment: Thanks that's what I found out. The issue is how do I pass the entire data to the c Function. I need to pass the entire 14070 bytes of data but now it's only passing part of it. 

I even tried to cha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246621/discussion-between-allthenutsandbolts-and-daniel-widdis).

Answer (score 1):

In C, a `char` is a byte.

In JNA, the most straightforward mapping of a pointer to a single byte is a `ByteByReference`.  After retrieving the pointer from your function, you'll use `getValue()` to fetch the `byte` (native `char`) it's pointing to.

However, C functions also have a byte pointer when they are pointing to the beginning of a block of data, and this is where you need more information to know how much data there is going to be so you can allocate it.  This is usually defined in the API for the function you use.

You've guessed by multiplying some constant by 2, since you are receiving 25097 bytes but only allocated space for 14070.  You've doubled that to 28140, but what if you now get 29000 bytes?  The API must either tell you its max vale or let you set the max value.  Doing neither is an error in the code you're using.

As for reading back a much shorter string, it is likely that the data you received is null-delimited, where subsequent strings are separated by a null byte. `Pointer.getString()` will read ASCII bytes up to the first null, and then stop.  You'd need to track the length of that String, add a byte, and read past the null until you get to the end of your buffer to read the remaining bytes.  Here's [some code in JNA](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/999c60a1fa0ab1154b07edffa3748ce46d8d3b89/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Advapi32Util.java#L976-L1001) that shows how that can be done.

Comment: Let me try that.